# Can a .NET web application run with only dlls and configs?

Tags: .net, publishing

I remember being told that you can run a .NET web application with only it's DLLs and without the various aspx, ascx asmx files (obviously any html and js files are still required).

Is it possible to publish a .NET web application by copying only the dlls, configs and client side resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of investigation I don't believe it's possible.

I uploaded just the DLLs (in a bin folder) and the web.config and it didn't work.  I added the remaining files and it did.